# Hadoop Mapreduce - Recursion

Tags: java, hadoop, recursion, mapreduce

I am a Hadoop newbie programmer. I had setup a multi-node cluster and I am aware of general working of a Hadoop mapreduce program. For one of my MapReduce projects, I have to work on wikipedia datasets. I have looked into mediawiki api and I have parsed the retrieved JSON. My query comes in the recursion part of MapReduce, For example if my wkipedia query term is "NOSQL" , I will have to build a tree of related words of NOSQL from the wikipedia article (ex : MongoDB...and so on) and from MongoDB the next level of tree which are related to mongoDB ( ex Sharding...and so on) and my depth of the tree can be a developer defined value (ex : 5 levels of depth). This kind of recursion, is it possible in MAP? Any pointers would be of great help.

Comment: Can you provide few examples along with the description? The input of `MAP` for example. That would be a great help.

Comment: @blackSmith, driver.java has a input file as similar to standard wordcount program. Ex: Apache, [Hbase, Hadoop, NoSQL, Hive...] Where Apache is the wikipedia search term and HBase and etc are their internal links ( I have calculated this seperately). MAP Phase key is (Text, List) = (Apache,[hbase,hadoop...]). Now I will have to find out the Internal links of Hbase, check if it has Apache or not and proceed with finding the internal links of its children upto 5 levels of depth. SO I will end up with a knowledge map kind of graph. That recursion was my question all about.

Comment: If I start with Hbase, lets say it has 50 children, I will have to draw a graph of the top 10 children ( some logic) and proceed with those 10 children, find their internal links and so on...upto 5 levels. So should I have to spawn Map() inside a Map(), recursion or any kind of pointers regarding this would be helpful.

Comment: Don't get me wrong but never seen recursion of `Map` method till date and I don't think it's a good idea. If recursion is indeed necessary use a private method to do the stuff and call it inside `Map`.

Comment: @blackSmith Thanks! Could you give any idea / pointers regarding the problem which I have exlpained above!

Comment: I would really like to but I've little knowledge on HBase.